# Docker Anaconda ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python, docker, anaconda

I am on Linux (Ubuntu) running a docker container that looks like

```
FROM continuumio/miniconda

COPY . /root_dir/

WORKDIR root_dir

RUN ["conda", "env", "create", "-f", "environment.yaml"]

ENV PYTHONPATH=/rootdir/src

CMD ["conda", "run", "-n", "kardia_env", "python", "run/entrypoint.py"]
```

The container builds fine and resolves the environment, however I get the error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'foo'` when I run it; `run/entrypoint.py` tries to import foo

I do not understand since `foo` is a subdirectory of `src` with an `__init__.py` file, and the PYTHONPATH has been updated to include `src`. Can anyone shed some light on to this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You are mispelling the `root_dir` folder name in your PYTHONPATH. This should fix the issue.

Change this:

```
ENV PYTHONPATH=/rootdir/src
```

To this:

```
ENV PYTHONPATH=/root_dir/src
```

Comment: Embarrassingly simple...